# Material v5 UI, concern of strict separation

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

I just upgraded some code from v4, where I had centralized the themes(theme,darktheme) and styles in one file called themes.js. All styled components were just under an useStyles function.

Moving to Material v5, and keeping everything centralized, but at the same time keeping up with separation. I needed to create a function that reads out of my now object like this:

```
  export const StyledComponents = (theme) => ({
   trainingmenu: {
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "row",
        justifyContent: "center",
        [theme.breakpoints.down("sm")]: {
            flexDirection: "column",
            alignItems: "center",
        },
});

export const getTrainingMenuStyles = (theme) => {
  const styles = StyledComponents(theme);
  return styles.trainingmenu;
};
```

and then import and create a function for each of my styled objects like this on the page/component I need it

```
import { getTrainingMenuStyles } from "../themes";
import { useTheme } from "@mui/material";
// other imports

export const Trainingselector = (props) => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const trainingMenuStyles = getTrainingMenuStyles(theme);

  // rest of the component
};
```

to then use it like this with sx

```
<RadioGroup
  sx={trainingMenuStyles}
  row
  name="Trainingprogram"
  value={valuePower}
  onChange={handleRadioChangePower}
>
```

This seems to me to be very convoluted way of doing it?

I understand that I can keep it more in line with v4 and do something along the lines of this:

```
// themes.js
export const styledComponents = (theme) => ({
    trainingmenu: {
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "row",
        justifyContent: "center",
        [theme.breakpoints.down("sm")]: {
            flexDirection: "column",
            alignItems: "center",
        },
    },
    // Other styles...
});
```

and then on the single page/component do this..

```
import { styledComponents } from "../themes";
import { useTheme } from "@mui/material";

const theme = useTheme();
const styles = styledComponents(theme);

// Radioform.js
<RadioGroup
    sx={styles.trainingmenu}
    row
    name="Trainingprogram"
    value={valuePower}
    onChange={handleRadioChangePower}
>
   
</RadioGroup>
```

But this last one is probably not completely correct vs this "concern of strict separation"

I'm not that well known with Material UI, so perhaps I'm not seeing the obvious here. Is there a smarter way of obtaining separation,but keeping the complexity down ?

Answer (score 0):

Could a **themes.js** file like this work for you?

### themes.js

```
/**
 * @file: themes.js
 */
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';

const theme = createTheme();

export const trainingmenu = ( function( theme ) {
    return {
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "row",
        justifyContent: "center",
        [theme.breakpoints.down("sm")]: {
            flexDirection: "column",
            alignItems: "center",
        },
    };
} )( theme );


export const someOtherStyle = ( function( theme ) {
    return {
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "row",
        justifyContent: "center",
        [theme.breakpoints.down("sm")]: {
            flexDirection: "column",
            alignItems: "center",
        },
    };
} )( theme );
```

...

Then to consume the styles...

### some other component

```
import { trainingmenu } from "../themes";
// other imports

export const Trainingselector = (props) => {
    // rest of the component

    <SomeComponent sx={ trainingmenu } />
};

...
```

Comment: yes, I agree that is a better way, much cleaner. thx!